# In form sorting using ransack gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I've been trying (unsuccessfully so far) to use the out of the box in-form sorting provided by the ransack gem, and the result of it unfortunately is an empty form.

**Here's what I've done so far:**

```
Controller:
    class LandingController < ApplicationController
      layout "landing2"
      def index
        @zones = Zone.all
        @zone_id ||= 1
        @q = Property.search(params[:q])
        @q.build_sort if @q.sorts.empty?
      end
    end
```

**View (partial):**

```
<%= search_form_for @q, :url => home_path, :html => { :method => :get } do |f| %>
  <%= f.sort_fields do |s| %>
    <%= s.sort_select %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Sort" %>
<% end %>
```

**And the result is:**

[image: Ransack sort form(empty)]

Does anybody know what could possibly be wrong?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you missed the line

```
@properties = @q.result(:distinct => true)
```

which should be after

```
@q = Property.search(params[:q])
```

Comment: Yeah! absolutely right ! Thanks for hearing my call for help ! :)